# What happens if I remove shared memory of other processes?

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

I was experimenting with shared memory and writing multiprocessing programs in C. I was using the ipcrm command to remove shared memory but I accidentally deleted shared memory not allocated by me or my program. Nothing happened except its key became 0x00000000. I was wondering if this is a dangerous thing to do because it may be critical for other processes.

On the other hand, what is the best way to store critical data so noobs like me won't crash processes?

Comment: How often have you yet crashed critical data? I wouldn't worry about it :-)

Comment: I typed `man ipcrm` into my terminal, and it told me, "A shared memory object is only removed after all currently attached processes have detached (shmdt(2)) the object from their virtual address space."

Comment: I haven't crashed anything. But, wouldn't putting it in shared memory seem dangerous? What happens if a rogue program or virus keeps using ipcrm to prevent any process from using shared memory? (Assuming virus scanner uses shared memory)

Comment: Oh. Some program didn't remove the shared memory after detaching I guess? And, my OS didn't clean it up yet.

Comment: Why do you care? If a system is compromised to a point where that is happening the user has bigger problems than not being able to run your application.

Comment: True, but what if the application is the virus scanner.

Comment: A program that uses ipcrm to remove shared memory spaces isn't too different conceptually from one that use rm to delete important files; either one would cause problems, and the solution in either case is either don't run destructive programs, or make sure that the destructive programs don't have permission to destroy your important stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current POSIX standard, shared memory is just a file for each process. Let's see the interface shm_open() which set up shared memory:

```
/* shm_open - open a shared memory file */
int shm_open (const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode)
{
  int fd;
  char shm_name[PATH_MAX+20] = "/dev/shm/";

  /* skip opening slash */
  if (*name == '/')
    ++name;

  /* create special shared memory file name and leave enough space to
    cause a path/name error if name is too long */
  strlcpy (shm_name + 9, name, PATH_MAX + 10);

  fd = open (shm_name, oflag, mode);

  if (fd != -1)
    {
      /* once open we must add FD_CLOEXEC flag to file descriptor */
      int flags = fcntl (fd, F_GETFD, 0);

      if (flags >= 0)
        {
          flags |= FD_CLOEXEC;
          flags = fcntl (fd, F_SETFD, flags);
        }

      /* on failure, just close file and give up */
      if (flags == -1)
        {
          close (fd);
          fd = -1;
        }
    }

  return fd;
}
```

We could see that shm_open() just create a file about the information of shared memory. When one process delete shared memory opened by itself, it will not affect other processes using the shared memory. That also means, the access to shared memory is not synchronized for processes.

For the second question, only root and owner of a process can use ipcrm to delete the shared memory file of a process, so it is probably a safe operation.